# VirtualBox VM remain large after file has been deleted

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I've question on Oracle VirtualBox, where I've moved a large file (80GB) into the VM, but after I deleted the large file, my VM still remain the same size but not free up.

any idea? please help

Comment: As this question is not programming related, you should ask this question in [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com). Concerning your question, I'm not sure if things have changed, but as far as I recall, once the space is allocated for a hdd image you are not able to shrink it again. For that you have to create a new hdd.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following command:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd your_hd.vdi --compact
```

You may also need to zero the free space first using a tool like [SDelete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443) from the SysInternals group at Microsoft.